# GeoMedia + WFS 1.1.0 -- how to specify a non-default SRS in a GetFeature request?

Tags: wfs, geomedia, getfeature

I'm forming a WFS post request like the one below.  Notice I have SRSNAME="epsg:4326":

```xml
<GetFeature xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" service="WFS"
version="1.1.0" maxFeatures="500">
  <wfs:Query typeName="SewerMainline" SRSNAME="EPSG:3857">
    <Filter xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
      <BBOX>
        <PropertyName>LinearGeometry</PropertyName>
        <Envelope srsName="EPSG:4326" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
          <lowerCorner>46.226130203549 -119.23339223652</lowerCorner>
          <upperCorner>46.226323539414 -119.23301630567</upperCorner>
        </Envelope>
      </BBOX>
    </Filter>
  </wfs:Query>
</GetFeature>
```

But the result looks like this.  Notice the geometry is still in EPSG:3857 (the DefaultSRS):

```xml
<gmgml:FeatureCollection xmlns="http://www.intergraph.com/geomedia/gml"
xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"
xmlns:gmgml="http://www.intergraph.com/geomedia/gml"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation='http://www.intergraph.com/geomedia/gml http://usalvwdgis1:801/WFS1/request.aspx?request=DescribeFeatureType&amp;VERSION=1.1.0&amp;SERVICE=WFS&amp;OUTPUTFORMAT=text/xml;subtype=gml/3.1.1'
numberOfFeatures='4'>
  <gml:boundedBy>
    <gml:Envelope srsName="EPSG:4326">
      <gml:lowerCorner>46.2260082243399 -119.233511477885</gml:lowerCorner>
      <gml:upperCorner>46.2262617590092 -119.232662186944</gml:upperCorner>
    </gml:Envelope>
  </gml:boundedBy>
  <gml:featureMember>
    <gmgml:SewerMainline gml:id="SewerMainline.5635">
      <gmgml:ID1>5635</gmgml:ID1>
      <gmgml:LinearGeometry>
        <gml:LineString srsName="EPSG:4326">
          <gml:posList srsDimension="2">46.2262145488833 -119.233114496317
          46.2262139292097 -119.233327445878</gml:posList>
        </gml:LineString>
      </gmgml:LinearGeometry>
    </gmgml:SewerMainline>
  </gml:featureMember>
</gmgml:FeatureCollection>
```

I've confirmed the service supports 4326..here is a snippet from GetCapabilities:

```xml
<ows:Parameter name="srsName">
  <ows:Value>EPSG:3857</ows:Value>
  <ows:Value>EPSG:4326</ows:Value>
</ows:Parameter>
```

I also looked at the WFS 1.1.0 spec and the doc on the SRSNAME state the following:

> This parameter is used to specify a WFS-supported SRS that should be
>   used for returned feature geometries. The value may be the DefaultSRS
>   or any of the OtherSRS values that a WFS declares it supports in the
>   capabilities document. The SRS may be indicated using EPSG codes or
>   the URL form defined in [2]. If the parameter is not specified then
>   the value of the DefaultSRS for the feature type being queried shall
>   be used.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Contacted Intergraph and they filed it as a defect:
SR 1-408131380 has been updated to CR - Defect / CR - Filed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I take it you're trying to reproject the data? According to the [documentation](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wfs/vendor.html):

> srsName= where  is the code for the projection (such
>   as EPSG:4326).
>
> For POST requests, you can add the same code to the Query element.

So you might want to putting it under the Query element.

Comment: I think that documentation relates to GeoServer running WFS 1.0.  I tried moving the SRSNAME to the Query and received the same response.

Comment: But you're trying to reproject yes? What WFS server are you using btw?

Comment: R.K. - I believe you are correct.  The WFS 1.1 Spec does re-state slightly more specifically that "the optional srsName attribute of the <Query> element is used to specify a specific WFS-supported SRS to be used for returned feature geometries. Its value may be the <DefaultSRS> or any of the <OtherSRS> values listed for the feature type in WFS capabilities document. If no srsName value is supplied, then the features shall be returned using the advertised <DefaultSRS> value."

Comment: So your WFS request works now?

Comment: No...I just believe you're suggestion was correct.  I've contacted Intergraph Support and will follow-up.

Comment: Okay. Glad to be of help then.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4806/discussion-between-r-k-and-ca0v)